# How can I override the ggplot function in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the `theme_bw` command in pretty much all of my R plots, so I was thinking of overriding the ggplot function like so:

```
# Override the ggplot function to use theme_bw by default
ggplot <- function(...) {
  ggplot(...) + theme_bw()
}
```

However, when I do this, the interpreter complains, saying

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Is there any way to specify that the ggplot inside the function should be the original version of ggplot, not the one I just wrote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `::` operator to specify that you want to call the version of the function that lives in the `ggplot2` package, not the version you just created in the global workspace.  i.e. something like

```
ggplot <- function(...) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(...) + theme_bw()
}
```

should work (although I haven't tested it!)

I also have a strong preference for `theme_bw()`.  The way I do it is to use `theme_set()` right after I load the package, e.g.

```
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
```

which arguably is just as easy and more idiomatic/transparent than your solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to modify your start-up code in the Rprofile.site document. (For Windows: It's in C:\Program Files\R\R-n.n.n\etc).

Add this code to it:

```
.First <- function(){
ggplot2::theme_set(theme_bw())
}
```

Anything in the .First will be run upon startup.